# Deserialisation unable to list data

Tags: c#, visual-studio, serialization

I am trying to create an application that can both serialise and deserialise data, i can serialise the information however when i try to read the information i am left with an empty list and i do not know why.

**My Serialization class**

```
  [Serializable()]
  public class FileSerilizeObject 
    {
        public static string FileName { get; set; }
        public static string Extension { get; set; }
        public static string Base64 { get; set; } 

        public FileSerilizeObject(string filename, string extension, string base64vaulue)
        {
            FileName = filename;
            Extension = extension;
            Base64 = base64vaulue;
        }

    }
}
```

**My serialization/deserialization methods**

```
 public void Serialize(List<FileSerilizeObject> List)
        {
            using (Stream stream = File.Open(savepath, FileMode.OpenOrCreate))
            {
                BinaryFormatter bin = new BinaryFormatter();
                bin.Serialize(stream, List);
                stream.Close();
            }

        }

        public List<FileSerilizeObject> Deserialised(string OpenPath)
        {
            List<FileSerilizeObject> defo;
            using(Stream stream = File.Open(OpenPath, FileMode.Open))
            {

                BinaryFormatter bin = new BinaryFormatter();
                defo = (List<FileSerilizeObject>)bin.Deserialize(stream);
            }

            return defo;
        }
```

I have checked to insure that the file paths are correct and that the file itself is not empty.Everything is fine however the "defo" list is always empty so i can only assume the issue is with the   `defo = (List<FileSerilizeObject>)bin.Deserialize(stream);`Line however i do not know why.

Answer (score 0):

Try to set the `[Serializable()]` attribute for each property.

So it would look like this:

```
[Serializable()]
public class FileSerilizeObject 
    {
        [Serializable()]
        public string FileName { get; set; }
        [Serializable()]
        public string Extension { get; set; }
        [Serializable()]
        public string Base64 { get; set; } 

        public FileSerilizeObject(string filename, string extension, string base64vaulue)
        {
            FileName = filename;
            Extension = extension;
            Base64 = base64vaulue;
        }

    }
}
```

EDIT: Removed `static` keyword from properties.

Comment: The compiler says that the  `[Serializable()]` attribute is not valid on this declaration type.

Comment: Alright, so you are trying to serialize the `FileName`, `Extension` and `Base64` properties of the `FileSerilizeObject` class, is this correct?

Comment: Yes i am trying to both serialise and deserialise that information.

Comment: The values of those properties will always be the same, because they are static.
Do you want that all items in the list have the same values?

Comment: Ah, no they change dynamically i only added that so i can access them from my main class because it was not letting me call the class as a new instance.

Comment: That's not gonna work, you have to remove the `static` keyword, only then every item will have individual values. See the code example from Praveen Paulose.

Answer (score 0):

You need to remove the static from your properties

```
[Serializable]
public class FileSerializeObject 
{
    public string FileName { get; set; }
    public string Extension { get; set; }
    public string Base64 { get; set; } 

    public FileSerializeObject(string filename, string extension, string base64vaulue)
    {
        FileName = filename;
        Extension = extension;
        Base64 = base64vaulue;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I tested your code into a console application and it is working for me, I tested with VS 2013 but I used the same code that you wrote above.

Some details:
1. I removed the word static form the "FileSerilizeObject"

**The class FileSerilizeObject**

```
 [Serializable()]
public class FileSerilizeObject
{
    public string FileName { get; set; }
    public string Extension { get; set; }
    public string Base64 { get; set; }

    public FileSerilizeObject(string filename, string extension, string base64vaulue)
    {
        FileName = filename;
        Extension = extension;
        Base64 = base64vaulue;
    }

}
```

**Functions**

```
public static void Serialize(List<FileSerilizeObject> List)
    {
        using (Stream stream = File.Open(@"C:\Users\ttest\Desktop\folder1\data.bin", FileMode.OpenOrCreate))
        {
            BinaryFormatter bin = new BinaryFormatter();
            bin.Serialize(stream, List);
            stream.Close();
        }

    }

    public static List<FileSerilizeObject> Deserialised(string OpenPath)
    {
        List<FileSerilizeObject> defo;
        using (Stream stream = File.Open(OpenPath, FileMode.Open))
        {

            BinaryFormatter bin = new BinaryFormatter();
            defo = (List<FileSerilizeObject>)bin.Deserialize(stream);
        }

        return defo;
    }
```

**Main**

```
var bytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("dffesdbcdef==");
        var base64 = Convert.ToBase64String(bytes);
        FileSerilizeObject f1 = new FileSerilizeObject("test", "jpg", base64);
        bytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("ggasddbcdef==");
        base64 = Convert.ToBase64String(bytes);
        FileSerilizeObject f2 = new FileSerilizeObject("test2", "png", base64);
        bytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("asddffasdasdasdesdbcdef==");
        base64 = Convert.ToBase64String(bytes);
        FileSerilizeObject f3 = new FileSerilizeObject("test3", "doc", base64);


        List<FileSerilizeObject> lFiles = new List<FileSerilizeObject>();
        lFiles.Add(f1);
        lFiles.Add(f2);
        lFiles.Add(f3);


        Serialize(lFiles);
        Deserialised(@"C:\Users\rjimen4x\Desktop\tutoriales\data.bin");
```